# Word for the river emptiyng into the ocean

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, meaning-in-context, translation

In Portuguese we have the word "desaguar", which would roughly translate to "to release water" but is almost exclusively used to mean the offloading of water by a river into another body of water. We use it as such:

> The Mississippi River "desagua" in the Atlantic.

Is there an equivalente word in English? It would be nice if the English word would "behave" in the same way as the Portuguese one, where it immediately makes the user think of a river, as opposed to for example the word "drain" which is far too general.

For reference, the sentence I am trying to translate is from a [song/poem](https://youtu.be/dm0TKuD_d9k) and reads

> The river from my land*, "desagua" in my heart.

*: Land could possibly be translated as home too.

Comment: A river **discharges** into the sea, but that word too has other connotations such as with drains and bodily functions.

Comment: I would say "The Mississippi River flows into the Gulf of Mexico" ... https://www.answers.com/Q/Does_the_Mississippi_River_flow_into_the_Gulf_of_Mexico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can say

> The Mississippi drains/empties/discharges/flows into the Gulf of Mexico.

The closest word for your purposes might be *flow*, which makes one immediately think of a liquid (although I guess blood flows as well as water, so the poem might acquire some new connotations.).

Comment: I think "flows" is _almost_ perfect! Also, I can't believe **the** Peter Shor just answered me, this is weird.